# Vim, Python and curses

Tags: python, vim, curses

I wrote a small python script for vim that uses the curses library.
When I try to call the function curses complains about:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/curses/__init__.py", line 33, in initscr
fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal
```

Don't know how to solve this

Edit: GVIM complains Vim works fine

Answer (score 7):

I'm not very sure about the context, but "GVIM complains Vim works fine" is very insightful: curses are used in the console, gvim is run in a X window, thus there's no console.